# Why in Laravel default model User, show method is set with "User $user"?

Tags: laravel, controller, get

Why the `show` method in the default `User` model comes with `User $user` as argument ?

I'm usually replacing it by `$id` in order to find a user with `return User::find($id);`, but does it mean that there's another way to retrieve user data ?

```
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        //
    }
```

=== EDIT ===

```
Route::get('/users/{id}', 'UserController@show');
```

=== EDIT ===

If I replace `{id}` by `{user}`, how should I set the `$user` variable ?

```
    async getUsers () {
      let $user = ?
      await axios.get('/show/'+ $user)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please share your route

Comment: @A.ANoman Route added. How would I use the default `User $user` instead of `$id` ?

Comment: DO you try yet ?? `Route::get('/users/{user}', 'UserController@show');`

Comment: It should be like this `await axios.get('/users/1')` where 1=>user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Route Binding: see the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding). Laravel will automatically replace your route parameter

> Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or
>   controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route
>   segment name. For example:
>
> ```
> Route::get('api/users/{user}', function (App\User $user) {
>    return $user->email;
> });
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this instructive reply! I have just updated my post to show how I'm calling the route.

Comment: From Axios, you send $user_id

Comment: Ok, thanks, very convenient indeed. Is there a similar way to get a collection of users if I provide `age`, `gender`, `city` or a mix of these attributes instead of the `id` ?

Comment: For anything beyond model id, you will have to do your logic in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

This is as simple as much

```
Route::get('/users/{user}', 'UserController@show');
```

If you use

```
Route::get('/users/{id}', 'UserController@show');
```

Then you write an extra code like

```
User::find($id);
```

So default is simple and less code

Comment: How should I set the {user} variable ? I have updated my post to show how I'm calling the route.